# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Shard type [region-DEVSYSTEM-48800] must be started first

Tags: scala, akka, cluster-computing

at akka.cluster.sharding.ClusterSharding.shardRegion(ClusterSharding.scala:512) ~[akka-cluster-sharding_2.11-2.5.13.jar:2.5.13]

The exception is occurring when the server is getting started in akka clustered environment.

Answer (score 0):

## Root Cause

This is happening, cause the ShardRegion actor is trying to process the persistent entity assigned to 48800 (present in the DB) but the persistent entity is not present in the memory.Hence ShardRegion actor is not getting initialized properly. It should be happening at below code.

ClusterSharding(system).shardRegion(48800)

## Solution

The persistent entity either should be removed from the DB or should be dealt that it should be present in the memory.